# how to merge the values of two objects into one using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap.

I Have 2 objects: `eup` and `gld`. The length of `eup` is 22, and the length of `gld` is 6.

I have tried:

```
//common.push(eup,gld);
//common.join(eup,gld);
//common.concat(eup,gld);

alert(common.length)  // 2
```

When I check `common.length`, it's 2.

But for my logic I need it as 1. That means merge `eup` and `gld` and shows its length as 1. I got the result of `eup` and `gld` from two different APIs and **it's in JSON format**.
The main thing is the tags of both objects are identical. So I think it should be possible to merge these values as one and show its length as ONE.

Is there any solution for this????

Comment: Which is the structure of those arrays?

Comment: why 1? length of final array should be 28 , right ?

Comment: Like this


{
  "company_data": {
    "doors": "2-4 Doors",
    "transmission": "Manual",
    "aircondition": "A/C",
    "CarSize": "xxxx",
    "type": "ss",
    "total_price": "1124.16"
  }
}

Comment: are you trying to merge two objects or arrays ?

Comment: @tracevipin I need this  : common.length = 1 

but now I got common.length = 2 (eup,gld)

Comment: @tracevipin : Two or more Arrys

Comment: not getting what you are trying to achieve . please give sample data for eup and gld

Comment: /* eur*/

{
  "company_data": {
    "doors": "2-4 Doors",
    "transmission": "Manual",
    "aircondition": "A/C",
    "CarSize": "xxxx",
    "type": "ss",
    "total_price": "1124.16"
  }
}

/*gld*/

{
  "company_data": {
    "doors": "6 Doors",
    "transmission": "Manual",
    "aircondition": "NoN",
    "CarSize": "yy",
    "type": "F",
    "total_price": "1124.16"
  }
}

Comment: these are not arrays, but objects in javascript. you need to ask how to merge two objects.

Comment: still... how did you get the length of eup as 22 and gld as 6 ? .. if you merge these two, properties will be overwritten ...

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to extend an object, not concatenate an array.

```
var common = $.extend({}, eup, gld);
```

However, this will overwrite values with common keys.  To merge without overwriting, the solution is explained at [Merge JS objects without overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549574/merge-js-objects-without-overwriting).

Comment: Or pure JS extend http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: @Derek :

Actually my requirement is;

In my application; I have two or more api’s . In its response as JSON format; there are lot of Tags are given in the Result but my required details are given in a Tag known as "company_data".
so now I’m collecting company_data details to an array in each respond file..

var eup =new Array();
var gld=new Array();
var common =new Array()

When I got the result from each API calling; its company_data are set to its array value.

Comment: @Amir, I apologize, but I cannot understand what you are saying.  Can you perhaps post what you expect `common` to look like?  Seeing the result will help eliminate confusion and give you a working solution. (BTW, don't use `new Array()`; use `[]` instead.)

Comment: @Derek Sorry.. I will explain my requirement once again. In my list there is 2 different companies (Actually its value is dynamic depends up on different countries); I got 2 companies details in JSON format. Here I have 2 API for 2 Companies.
company1.php and company2.php
And I got 2 Different JSON data.
But here the JSON both are same format that means Tags are same in Both JSON and only the values are different.Then I need to merge the values of 2 different JSON data to a common array.For this;
var eur =new Array();
var gld=new Array();
var common =new Array();

Comment: 1st api result set to Array "eru"  and 2nd api result set to Array "gld"..
currently this purpose is OK. To get the values as one ; I tried to set the values of two different arrays "eru  and gld" to a Common Array.
For this method; I tried; 
common.push(eup,gld);
common.join(eup,gld);
common.concat(eup,gld);
alert(common.length) 
In this case; I got the common.length=2.
But Actually I need the length "common.length=1".
The concept is I need to set the values of both Arrays in to Common Array and shows as one... :(

Comment: @Amir, I'm not asking you to explain.  You've tried that, and we aren't understanding you.  Rather than explain, show.  Show me what you expect `common` to look like after you've joined/merged/whatevered. Then, by seeing the expected result, I can understand what you need and what needs to be done to get there.