# How to add a property from another object if it doesn't exist in the first object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two objects, obj1 and obj2. If obj2 has a key that obj1 doesn't have, that obj2 key/value pair gets added to obj1.

for example:

```js
obj1 = {
a:1,
b:2
}
obj2 = {
b:4,
c:3
}
```

c:3 would be put into obj1.

Here's what I have as an attempt, but my brain is being run in circles by this. I can't modify the 2nd object at all (don't need to), and i have to keep the value in obj1 if it also exists in obj2.

```js
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  
  function comparison(obj1,obj2){
      var object1keys = Object.keys(obj1)
      var object2keys = Object.keys(obj2)
      var flag = 0
      for(var i = 0; i<object2keys.length;i++){
          flag = 0
          for(var j = 0; j<object1keys.length;j++){
              if(object2keys[i] === object1keys[j]){
                  flag = 1
                  console.log(i,j)
                  break
              }
              if(flag = 0 && j == object1keys.length - 1){
                  obj1[i] = obj2[j]
              }
          }
      }
      return obj1
  }
 return obj1
}
```

Edit:This is a unique question because it looked like the other question didn't involve adding a specific key:value pair that didn't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge JS objects without overwriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549574/merge-js-objects-without-overwriting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution using `Object.keys()` and `Object.hasOwnProperty()` functions:

```js
var obj1 = {a:1,b:2}, obj2 = {b:4,c:3};

Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(k) {
  if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(k)) obj1[k] = obj2[k];
});

console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: wow thank you that was so much simpler than i thought. I certainly made a mountain out of that molehill

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(key) {
    obj1[key] = obj2[key];
  })
  return obj1;
}

console.log(extend({
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}, {
  b: 3,
  c: 4
}))
```